# Populate source - destination pairs and a flag from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `list` that has a source to destination stream and looks like -

```
path_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```

I want to populate a `DataFrame` for the list above that has 3 columns -
 `source, destination, flag`. Example -

```
source destination flag
 'A'      'A'      Type_1
 'A'      'B'      -
 'B'      'C'      -
 'C'      'C'      Type_2
```

I want to populate the `flag` column based on the rule - If first 2 entries in the `list` are same then `Type_1` and if the last 2 entries are same then `Type_2`. All other source-destination pairs will be flagged as `-`

I am halfway through and have a script that populates the `source` and the `destination` columns -

```
pd.DataFrame({'source': path_list[:-1], 'destination': path_list[1:]})
```

How do I add the flag column and populate it?

Comment: what if  first 2 entries in the list are not same?

Comment: populate `-` for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to give particular cell value use `df.flag.iat[0]`

```
import pandas as pd

path_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': path_list[:-1], 'destination': path_list[1:]})
df['flag'] = '-'

if path_list[0] == path_list[1]:
    df.flag.iat[0] = 'Type_1'

if path_list[-1] == path_list[-2]:
    df.flag.iat[-1] = 'Type_2'
print(df)
```

**output:**

```
  source destination   flag
0      A           A  Type_1
1      A           B      -
2      B           C      -
3      C           C  Type_2
```

Answer (score 2):

DataFrame is created from `path_list`, so only assign new list with first and last value and repeated `-`:

```
path_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame({'source': path_list[:-1], 'destination': path_list[1:]})

df['flag'] = ['Type_1'] + ['-'] * (len(df) - 2) + ['Type_2']
print (df)
  source destination    flag
0      A           A  Type_1
1      A           B       -
2      B           C       -
3      C           C  Type_2
```

But if need align values by first 2 and last 2 values of list create `MultiIndex` and set by `loc`:

```
#DataFrame with different order
print (df)
  source destination
0      A           B
1      B           C
2      A           A
3      C           C


path_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

df = df.set_index(['source','destination'])
df['flag'] = '-'
df.loc[tuple(path_list[:2]), 'flag'] = 'Type_1'
df.loc[tuple(path_list[-2:]), 'flag'] = 'Type_2'

df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  source destination    flag
0      A           B       -
1      B           C       -
2      A           A  Type_1
3      C           C  Type_2
```

Comment: `df['flag'] = ['Type_1' if path_list[0] == path_list[1] else '-'] + ['-'] * (len(df) - 2) + ['Type_2' if path_list[-1] == path_list[-2] else '-']`
should be like this? for the condition mentioned by the user

Comment: @Nihal - I am still thinking if I understand well